# "Operation System not found" Dell XPS 15Z L511Z

Tags: boot, dell, system-installation, 14.04, lts

Although title is the same problem is different.

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty on my HP EliteBook 6930p Notebook. And I was trying to create a bootable usb for my DELL XPS 15z. After successful creation of usb with `usb-creator-gtk` I plugged in bootable usb stick to DELL laptop.

The error message was "Operation System not found".

I tried several things but could not make it.

When I check from working Ubuntu, I can see that usb is bootable and has files for installation.

Comment: Did you try to change boot order, running from another computer, creating USB with UNetBootIn?

Comment: Yes but nothing changed. I also tried the stick on different laptop works well. Installation screen appears. But stupid DELL! I'll never buy a DELL again!

Comment: Can you post a photo of Dell BIOS page on which you set boot order?

Comment: http://goo.gl/2ljmjX here is it. Also while booting from F12 i choose USB device to boot.

Comment: Probably it should be listed under Hard Drive, not in USB storage.

Comment: When checked at BIOS i can see it on USB devices section. Not a Hard Drive.

Comment: Well, on my computer USB devices are listed in Hard Drive. Give it a try.

Comment: http://goo.gl/IP01fp No way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I tried and apply.

Problem definition:

First of all to point problem I should say. I was having dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10.

After installing Windows 8.1 everythings seems to be ok. One bloddy monday morning with unknown mistical reason Windows 8.1 stopped working. The error was "unmountable_boot_volume". I could not understand what happened. Six months no problem with SSD disk. But a monday morning it stucked on this error. And there is no solution for it. Everybody said just "Format it!".

Then I decied to move Linux Ubuntu 14.04, no dual boot. And the problem was as is written up.

Solution:
DELL XPS 15Z (L511Z) comes with PXE network boot.
I've installed TFTP and BOOTP service to another well working Ubuntu 14.04. Then boot the DELL and finally installed Ubuntu 14.04.

Conclusion:
Never use a Windows! as a Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell XPS 15z was one of the early devices with UEFI, I think it has bugs in the firmware, the latest UEFI BIOS was A12. However, it doesn't support booting GPT from what I found, so this can be a reason for the "Operating system not found message" so you might need to ensure any USB created is legacy MBR.

Furthermore, I have had issues with USB booting generally even when they are legacy MBR formatted and supported, the only way I found to resolve that was to clear the CMOS, you have to disconnect the battery then the CMOS battery and leave it for around a minute, then plug in the main battery and CMOS again.

On booting up it will warn you about the RTC being reset and you'll need to go into the setup to set the date/time again and commit the changes which will stop it from bleeping and this cleared USB boot issues.